# Sidekiq randomly emptying queue

Tags: ruby, sidekiq

I run into a weird issue with Sidekiq : My queues are randomly emptied.

The last time it occured, I had +/-5000 jobs in queue, and the next minute, they were all gone (but not done)

Is there some limitation I don't know about? Is this a configuration error on my side?

Thanks for helping

Comment: you might be used `.clear` in your code

Comment: @Gagan : I don't find any mention of `.clear`in my code